Characterising the nature of Eigen values of a given paramteric matrix
question: A{2x2} = https://files.oaiusercontent.com/file-rZmIDJV1d2325YK6eQfPFTo1?se=2024-07-18T09%3A30%3A45Z&sp=r&sv=2023-11-03&sr=b&rscc=max-age%3D299%2C%20immutable%2C%20private&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3D95b381bc-915f-407c-9b5f-2c76028433d8&sig=qtjoQEzA7dPr3gm53FOxDVEQQCIBR/55mRXYSDkuMyU%3D

A =[ 2  1 ]
[ 0  k ]

find; the values of k for which all the eigen values are greater than 0.
soln provided without reason:
k>1/2 taking |A|>0.
is it true that, Eigen values of a matrix A are all positive when the determinant of A is greater than 0? and how?is it universally true for any matrix of size?.
Basic method:
I have done it by solving the characteristic equation( |A - lambda.I|=0) and then found the value of  arbitrary 'K' using the nature of roots . i concluded that 4ac > 0 was the required condition that shows K>1/2

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
